# Memory location on stack is accessible even after function call has finished

Tags: c, stack

I have below program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* testPointerReturnType();

int main(void)
{
    int x = 2;
    printf("Value of x is %d and its address is %p\n", x, &x);
    int* y = testPointerReturnType();
    printf("Value of y is %d and its address is %p\n", *y, y);    
}

int* testPointerReturnType()
{
    int x = 33;
    int r = 99;
    return &x;
}
```

Below is my overall o/p (I will discuss this in my questions coming below):

```
// This is with ** int r = 99; ** line commented
jharvard@appliance (~/psets/pset5/pset5_test): ./PointerAddresss 
Value of x is 2 and its address is 0xbfdba7c4
Value of y is 33 and its address is 0xbfdba794
jharvard@appliance (~/psets/pset5/pset5_test): size PointerAddresss
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1250     280       4    1534     5fe PointerAddresss


// This is with ** int r = 99; ** line un-commented
jharvard@appliance (~/psets/pset5/pset5_test): ./PointerAddresss 
Value of x is 2 and its address is 0xbf8a98e4
Value of y is 33 and its address is 0xbf8a98b4
jharvard@appliance (~/psets/pset5/pset5_test): size PointerAddresss
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1266     280       4    1550     60e PointerAddresss
jharvard@appliance (~/psets/pset5/pset5_test):
```

Below are my question:

1. I am returning memory address of a local variable but still I am able to access that location later, after that function has finished execution. How? Is it possible that memory location still holds that value and has not been overridden. This means that if my program has called only one function and that function is returning a memory address then still I can access the local variables memory address and get same exact value because no other function has been called?
2. If I keep `int r = 99;` as commented then I get `1250` in text and dec. And if I uncomment then I get `1266`, which basically means increase of 16 memory locations, but int of 4 bytes when why increase of 16 memory locations? Also, I know text/code segment then what is `dec`?

Comment: Why would you think that CPU cycles would be wasted in wiping clear memory popped off the stack? Data is still there until overwritten but it is undefined behavior to try to access it.

Comment: @JohnColeman That's what I also thought but I wasn't sure and by notes/tutorial wasn't clear to point it out. How about my second question?

Comment: I think that @DavidHoelzer's answer nailed your second question

Comment: @JohnColeman : From the perspective of a *C/C++* standard it would be undefined, but at the assembler level it may be an implementation detail on the platform. On 64-bit Linux the System V ABI actually allows for the use of the stack below the current value of _RSP_ . It is called the red-zone (and is 128 bytes), and as long as you are a leaf function (doesn't call other functions) you can assume any values you place there will not be clobbered. The assembly code generated from optimized *C/C++* on x86-64 code usually takes advantage of this when suitable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is certainly possible that the memory location still holds the value unless the stack has again increased in size enough to overwrite the value, but you are operating based on undefined behavior.  It *might* mean that no other function has been called, but it also *might* mean that no other function needed to allocate that much space on the stack in order to operate.

The reason that you are seeing more memory allocated than you expected is because of stack alignment.  If you read the application binary interface documentation for your platform you will find this well described.

I hesitate to mention this, but if you mark the local variable in the function as `static`, you are still doing very bad things but you could reliably continue to access the value after the function call ends via a pointer because the value would no longer be allocated on the stack.

Finally, I just saw your last question.  `dec` means decimal.  If you convert 0x60e to decimal you will get 1550.

---

*David's more information about stack alignment, putting into his answer from his comments - hagrawal.*

> Stack alignment is required for speed of access to elements and for
>   consistency in calling. This way things are best aligned in memory for
>   fast access and the called function doesn't have to "wonder" where
>   things will be. This means that allocating one byte will often result
>   in 2, 4, 8, 16 or even more bytes being allocated on the stack, all
>   depending on the alignment requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. For first question that's what I also thought but I wasn't sure and by notes/tutorial wasn't clear to point it out. For second question - stack alignment? I did heard about data structure alignment but not stack alignment. I will read more about this on web but if could throw some light on it and important points related to it then it would be good for me and also other future readers. I knew about the `static` thing and operating about undefined behavior. One question is still unanswered - "*what is `dec`*". It would be great if you could throw light this as well.

Comment: Stack alignment is required for speed of access to elements and for consistency in calling.  This way things are best aligned in memory for fast access and the called function doesn't have to "wonder" where things will be.  This means that allocating one byte will often result in 2, 4, 8, 16 or even more bytes being allocated on the stack, all depending on the alignment requirements.

Comment: Oh, I answered the dec thing... last paragraph

Comment: Thanks mate, I read your `dec` thing. It means it is memory location in decimal? And what is this memory location for - function or variable? Start location or end location? Please confirm.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that tool, but since you were calling "size" I'm guessing that the DEC and HEX columns are showing you the size in decimal and hex of what's being analyzed.  You may have to go to the manual for that one. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I edited your answer, hope you will not mind.

Comment: This statement may be part of the story _Stack alignment is required for speed of access to elements and for consistency in calling._ . Often it is a requirement for those instructions that will fault with unaligned data. Many libraries for x86-64 now are generated with SIMD instructions that work only on aligned data. So if you have a value not properly aligned (including the stack) you could end up with seg faults. On PPC you may end up with a bus error with improper alignment.